# jquery on.click doesn't work on first click (with a dynamic element)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, onclick, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm struggling with the following problem: I dynamically create input elements and I try to attach a datepicker to it. But it works only when I click somewhere outside the input element and then on the input again. Console log is working fine on first click, so I don't know what is the issue here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("div.single_condition").on("click", "input", function(){
        if($("select.select_operator").val() == '>'){
            console.log("O.K.");
            $(this).datepicker();
        }
        else {
            console.log("NOT O.K.");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use `....datepicker();` after you are generating them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if you bind a datepicker to your input correctly using `.datepicker()`, you need to show it on first click.

Try this code,

```
$(this).datepicker().datepicker("show");
```

### **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/A2h9a/)**

**Changed JS** :

```
$("div.single_condition").on("click", "input", function () {
    if ($("select.select_operator").val() == '>') {
        console.log("O.K.");
        $(this).datepicker().datepicker("show");
    } else {
        console.log("NOT O.K.");
    }
});
```

***Suggestion*** : Bind the `.datepicker()` after you append the dynamic elements instead of on `click`.

Comment: I have another problem now. I want it to work only on specific conditions. I've created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/446hJ/

I want last 3 options to destroy datepicker, but when I choose something datepicker is shown for the first time on click. Later,it's disabled. How to rewrite this script not to show datepicker for the first time when I choose <d  >d  or =d   ?

Comment: Works like charm, thx a lot. I tried to implement the behaviour with the change function but now I see what I was doing wrong :)