# on('click'....) only fires after the second click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Here's the script.  When I click it on load, works like a charm.  When I click it via a dynamically created element, the first click sees the actual html shift (kind of stretch and go back).  It does however work on the second click consistently.

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.iframe_add', function(){        
    var element = $(this).attr('name');
    $('#iframe_target').html('<iframe src="https://104.131.18.58/t3/default/ajax_new_secured_asset_debt_creator?all='+element +'" frameborder="0" width="580" height="300" scrolling="yes" id="myFrame"></iframe>');
});    
</script>
```

I dont really get whats going on and Id  appreciate any help.

P.S. I saw this one, but am not sure if it applies (seems to deal with some datepicker issues)
[jquery on.click doesn't work on first click (with a dynamic element)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24487664/jquery-on-click-doesnt-work-on-first-click-with-a-dynamic-element)

EDIT:

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="iframe_modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Information</h4>
      </div>
      <div id="iframe_target" class="modal-body">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT 2 - Console Logs (all the same):

```
<a href="#iframe_modal" name="14-1136--Debts_secured-asset_page" class="iframe_add" data-toggle="modal">New</a>
```

Comment: What is the first static parent above '.iframe_add'?

Comment: if you `console.log` element, is it the same for the first and second click? i'm wondering if using `this` vs `event.target` is not the same thing for the dynamically generated instance

Comment: PhilVarg: When I do console.log ( '#someButton was clicked' ); it writes every time.  Its just that the iframe modal only displays on the second go around....

Comment: do `console.log(this)`. i want to know if the context of `this` is changing, and thus causing strange results. you're indirectly using `this` instead of `event.target`; `this` which can change for delegated events

Comment: My guess is the `name` attribute isn't set correctly in the element you're clicking on.

Comment: The result of the console.log(this) is in an edit above.  Too ugly in a comment.

Comment: There is a discrepancy: Your js targets the `iframe_add` class but your elements have the `iframe_input`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your console log:

```
<a href="#iframe_modal" name="14---asset-asset_page" class="iframe_input btn btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">New</a>
```

reveals that one of the classes is `iframe_input`.

Your JavaScript is telling us that you want the click event to fire when an element with a class named `.iframe_add` is clicked.

Try

```
$(document).on('click', '.iframe_input', function(){
```

Comment: Sadly, this is because I was sloppy in my logging.  When I do it for the iframe_add class, I get this each time.  (I have two functions that do roughly the same thing and I was logging both.  Ive edited the output above.

Comment: @mmb21167 No problem. Would you be able to get a lite JSFiddle up and running so we can test?

Comment: In fiddling, I think I found the culprit, though Im not sure what to do....Commenting these out means I cant get rid of my modal without clicking out, but it does alleviate the two click problem.  Thoughts?



parent.document.getElementsByClassName("modal-backdrop")[0].style.display = \'none\'; 
                                 parent.document.getElementById("iframe_modal").style.display = \'none\';

Comment: @mmb21167 For clarity, when you write "Commenting these out", does "_these_" mean the two lines of code at the end of your comment?

Comment: Yes. The two lines beginning w parent. When they are commented the modal obviously doesn't disappear manually but the 2 click problem resolves.

Comment: I really need to see more code, my friend. :/ And you're killing me here because I want to help figure this out haha.

Comment: (Thinks to self, "This is what I do with my Fridays?" SHM hahah

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So here is the hackity-hack solution I came up with (if you cant beat em -- and by em, I mean javascript, join em):

```
parent.document.getElementsByClassName("iframe_input")[0].click();
```

I just force a click on the first input element when the modal hides and this seems to resolve the behavior.  That being said, this seems really hacky and Im all ears as to why this is wrong but it does work like a charm....

Answer (score 0):

You must check if you don`t get error -> Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
If yes you must add code document.getElementById('xxx_element_name_xxx').addEventListener('click', xxx_function_name_xxx, true); after place where your element xxx_element_name_xxx was declared.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue in my ASP.Net Web Form. My case is I create toggle button to hide and display div.

I get rid this problem by embeded the initial style during loading page which is display: none at div itself rather than put it in external css file.

```
<div id="toggleDiv" style="style:none">
</div>
```